# making a small icon like buttons when clicking on textbox css

Tags: html, css

I have a form in which when I click on textbox I want to icon like buttons too on the bottom right just like JIRA and want to have insert emoticons and few other option like in JIRA

[image]

I have added CSS for that when I click on textbox, how to add button when my textbox is clicked on bottom right and inserting emoticons option would also be helpful

```
.answer input:focus{
  background: white;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid royalblue ;
  float: bottom !important;
  height: 75px;
}
```

Comment: It's possible to show or hide sibling elements when you focus the textarea using CSS alone. However interacting with any of the toolbars will cause the textarea to lose focus and hide the toolbar, which probably isn't desired. Therefore you will need JavaScript to ensure the textarea retains focus when you click another element in one of the toolbars.

Answer (score -1):

Since textarea and inputs don't support `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, safest bet would be to use a sibling selector to display the icon on focus.  Each wrapped on a container element, so it can be relative positioned in order to absolute position the icon where it should be

```css
.wrapper{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}

textarea{
  width:200px; height:150px;
}
textarea:focus + .icon{
  /*here would be your icon*/
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px; right:10px;
  width:30px; height:30px; 
  border-radius:50%;
  background:chartreuse;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="icon"> </div>
</div>
```